# Media autoplays when USB drive is opened from the Unity menu

Tags: 11.10, music, usb-drive, automount

An annoying change I've experienced upon upgrading to 11.10 is that when a USB device is opened from the unity menu, any media (i.e. music and videos) contained on it are autoplayed with whatever media player is my default. This is very rarely desirable, but I can't seem to find the option to turn it off!

Note that I've already checked the "never prompt or start programs on media insertion" box in System Settings for removable media. The problem doesn't occur when I insert the USB drive, only when I click the icon or select "open" from the unity menu (everything's fine if I open it within Nautilus).

Am I missing something super obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens when you click on the trash icon?

Comment: Oooh! Same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Look in the [Default Applications] section  for a line

```
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

delete the complete line, save

There is a new nautilus that fixes this for upgraders but still is in proposed, the above action will take care of this for you

bug I have on this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/876788